# How to write a function for different sample sizes to do same task

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have written some functions in R with different sample sizes and will like to have an anova fit for each of the sample sizes. Please can anyone help me as to how to write a code that does it once for each one of them? ns represents the different sample sizes.

```
ns=c(16,18,22,30)
x=rnorm(ns/2,2,5)
y=rnorm(ns/2,0,1)
yy=c(y,x)
xx=c(rep(0,ns/2),rep(1,ns/2))
fitt=lm(yy~xx)
anova(fitt)
(ns/2-1)*var(x)+(ns/2-1)*var(y))/((2*ns/2)-2)
```

Comment: What is exactly the output you are looking for? The whole `anova` or some parts of it? Also, what does this line do and do you need its output too? `(ns/2-1)*var(x)+(ns/2-1)*var(y))/((2*ns/2)-2)`. Please post a desired output

Comment: Alright please take out the last statement but what I want is the anova(fitt) for 16, that for 18 and so on up to 30, writing a program to do it once rather than one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
loopAnovafunc <- function(temp) {
  x <- rnorm(temp/2,2,5)
  y <- rnorm(temp/2,0,1)
  yy <- c(y,x)
  xx <- c(rep(0,temp/2),rep(1,temp/2))
  fitt <- lm(yy~xx)
  anova(fitt)
}

ns <- c(16,18,22,30)
lapply(ns, loopAnovafunc)
```

Comment: Thanks David but can you please explain the last part of the output